# Show and update the last line of a text file processed with PHP on a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, setinterval

i'm having trouble updating and printing the current value of a variable with  a JavaScript function. 
i have a text file constantly getting updated with sensor data from an usb serial interface, and used  this to look the last line of the log and save it to print it in a local server:

```
<h1 id="piecesCounter" style = "font-size: 120;">   
        <?php 
$line = '';
$f = fopen('...\counter.txt', 'r');
$cursor = -1;
fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
$char = fgetc($f);

while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
}

while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {

    $line = $char . $line;
    fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
    $char = fgetc($f);
}
        ?>  
</h1>
```

it works well, after obtaining the last value i wrote this script to print and update the value without having to reload the entire page:

```
<script>

var line = <?php echo $line ?>;
setInterval(updateCounter, 150);

function updateCounter () {
        document.getElementById("piecesCounter").innerHTML = line;
}

    </script>
```

The value shows but it does not update, i have to reload the entire page to see the changes in the value, i searched if theres a way to directly read the last line of the text file with JavaScript but didn't find concrete solutions.

Comment: I could be wrong... but don't you need to put a function before the code that calls it? otherwise: do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: You will have to use ajax to achieve this.

Comment: @ManuelOtto is right. The reason it doesn't change the value is because `$line` isn't being updated. Remember that PHP is serverside code. It's run before output! So once the output is on your webpage, it no longer runs. You'll need to use Ajax in order to call a seperate PHP file (or the same file with the PHP code) so PHP actually updates the value.